# Hadoop namenode shut down

Tags: java, apache, hadoop

My hadoop version is 0.20.203.0. The namenode running on my hadoop clulser was shut down. I checked the logs, and found the error message only in the secondary name logs:

```
2014-09-27 22:18:54,930 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Checkpoint done. New Image Size: 29552383
2014-09-27 22:19:42,792 INFO org.mortbay.log: org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet@8135daf JVM BUG(s) - injecting delay2 times
2014-09-27 22:19:42,792 INFO org.mortbay.log: org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet@8135daf JVM BUG(s) - recreating selector 2 times, canceled keys 38 times
2014-09-27 23:18:55,508 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of transactions: 0 Total time for transactions(ms): 0Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 0 SyncTimes(ms): 0 
2014-09-27 23:18:55,508 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Fatal Error : All storage directories are inaccessible.
2014-09-27 23:18:55,509 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

There was anonther error message apprears in one of my datanodes:

```
2014-09-27 01:03:58,535 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(10.75.6.51:50010, storageID=DS-532990984-10.75.6.51-50010-1343295370699, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020):DataXceiver
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskOutOfSpaceException: No space left on device
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.checkDiskError(DataNode.java:770)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver.receivePacket(BlockReceiver.java:475)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver.receiveBlock(BlockReceiver.java:528)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.writeBlock(DataXceiver.java:397)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.run(DataXceiver.java:107)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Not sure whether this is the root cause of the namenode shutting down issue?

New error raised when I was trying to restart the namenode?

```
2014-09-28 11:25:06,202 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
java.io.IOException: Incorrect data format. logVersion is -31 but writables.length is 0. 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog.loadFSEdits(FSEditLog.java:542)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadFSEdits(FSImage.java:1009)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadFSImage(FSImage.java:827)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:365)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:97)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:379)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:353)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:434)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1162)

Is there anyone knows about it ?  Is it possible to fix the imagne and editor files as I don't want to lose the data?
```

Comment: Share your entries in your hdfs-site.xml file